# How to connect with mysql in config file?

Tags: mysql, node.js

What im trying to do is to connect MySQL database in my project in the config file.

config/db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mydatabase'
})

const connectDb = async () => {
  const conn = await connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error("error: ", err.message);
    }

    console.log("Connected to MySql server");
  });
};
```

server.js

```
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

connectDB();
```

I have done this by fare and in my terminal is shown this error: TypeError: connectDb is not a function

How can I connect MySQL in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to export the connection verb, and delete the whole "connectDb" function

config/db.js

```js
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mydatabase'
})

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

server.js

```js
const database = require("./config/db");
database.queryOrAnythignElse();
```

You'll probably want to learn again the basics of js and what is module.exports and etc...

Comment: what is queryoranythingelse ...

Comment: The connection methods, like .query, .config and etc... It's just an example and to show you that you don't need to call a connection function in order to do this one simple task.

Comment: I have worked with mongo.db and the connection was in this way, and wanted to make it same with mysql

Comment: i know its a simple task, no need to tell

Comment: Alright you had an issue and i sent you the working example so you know... mysql and sql database are working a bit different from no-sql dbs